# IELTS Questions

Tags: ielts

This is the first time I am asking a question on this site. So I don't know if my questions are off-topic. If they are, please tell me from where can I get answers for them. Thank you. So here are my questions.

1) About Yes, No, Not Given type of question, we have to write 'Yes' or just 'Y'?

2) I had a question in Listening, like "... January", so are all of 25, 25th, 25^{th} acceptable?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about English but how to respond in an exam paper

Comment: In the Reading Paper, you must write in full one of the following:1. ***YES***, 2. ***NO*** -or- 3. ***NOT GIVEN***

Comment: For writing dates, it depends on the actual question, but generally either 25 or 25th should be fine. This 2nd question is still off topic IMO because we need to see  the original question to be absolutely certain. I have no idea what **25^** is, but it's incorrect for dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IELTS papers aren't vague by any means - they come with very specific instructions, and that can depend on the question being asked, so it's not really feasible for anybody to say definitively that you should answer Y or N - that will be stated on the paper. That being said, I would sincerely doubt that you will be penalised on your choice of date format, as long as the correct date is entered, and a *standard* date format is used. Standard date formats would be **25**, or **25th** ‒ **25^{th}** would not fall into that category. **^** is used to denote '*to the power of*' (for example (3^2 = 9), not superscript, as you are trying to do.

The best advice I can give you is to **read the instructions carefully** for each question, and **answer accordingly**.

[edit]

I did dig an old IELTS paper out of a drawer here to take a closer look, and it states:

> Do the following statements reflect the claims of the writer in the
>   passage above?
>
> In boxes 3-6 on your answer sheet write
>
> **YES** if the statement reflects the claims of the writer
>
> **NO** if the statement contradicts the claims of the writer
>
> **NOT GIVEN** if it is impossible to say what the writer thinks about this

Based on this question, the instructions are pretty explicit that in this case, 'YES', 'NO', and 'NOT GIVEN' should be written out in whole, in order to answer the question.

However, I would still advise reading the exam paper carefully, to make sure that you are following the instructions, as stated on the exam paper.

Comment: thank you, what about the second question?

Comment: Is it okay now, @Mari-LouA? Can you answer the second question for me? I'm just a student trying to find an answer here

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I respectfully disagree. Changes in question paper format happen all the time, so short of actually having access to the paper the OP is sitting/about to sit, *read the instructions carefully for each question, and answer accordingly* is the best advice anybody could give in this situation, in my opinion.

Comment: That being said, I did dig an old IELTS paper out of a drawer here to satisfy my curiosity, and it states:

Do the following statements reflect the claims of the writer in the passage above?
In boxes 3-6 on your answer sheet write
YES if the statement reflects the claims of the writer
NO if the statement contradicts the claims of the writer
NOT GIVEN if it is impossible to say what the writer thinks about this

The instructions are pretty explicit that for this particular question, 'YES', 'NO', and 'NOT GIVEN' should be written out in whole, in order to answer the question.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - fair point on the 25^{th} - that didn't register with me. Will update my reply accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get your first question exactly... If you are saying whether to write "Yes" or just "Y" in the answer sheet then it depends upon your the paper. The instructions will be given there and you should try to read them once... As of what I can see, it would be better to write "Yes"

As of your second question, if you are asking how are we supposed to write the date then it should be "25th of January". "25 of January" would be wrong and shouldn't be acceptable.